# How to select rows from a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe such this:

```
     Gene Interattore
1     fkh         P32
2  Tango9         phr
3   Noa36     CG11635
4   Noa36      CG3062
5 CG10014         Cam
6     drm      CG2316
```

and a vector such this:

```
common_DEG:
  [1] "Cdc42"      "Prat2"      "Got2"       "nst"        "puc"        "slgA"       "CG4546"     "Got2"       "CG7470"    
 [10] "Got2"   ........
```

I would design a dataframe where in column "Gene" of my dataframe there are only the genes contained in my vector with respective "interactor".

Answer (score 0):

try `df[df$Gene %in% common_DEG, ]`